how to host a website form xampp publicly?
I created a website using wordpress and it is hosted locally using xampp .But how can I host it publicly?
without buying a domain can I test it any free server?
Thanks for your help, and sorry if my question is confusing .
I have no idea what steps to take now

technically you can host a website from your localhost - but it will be a technical task and will take quite a long time.  either you have to set up port forwarding, or use a tool like ngrok.com to provide a public URL that tunnels to your local web server.

would be easier to just buy a cheap hosting plan tbh

We can use free hosting provider services to host your WordPress site publicly. Some popular free hosting services include InfinityFree, 000WebHost, and AwardSpace.
I believe it should help.
